# jquery checbox ( use as product comparison list )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im new to Jquery and I am struggling with the following ; I have a list of products, which I would like to add to a comparison list. User selects product (checkbox) and values are stored in an array and display in div.

I am having difficulty achieving the following :

- Limit `chckArray` to store only 2 values ( 2products ) or limit user from checking more than 2 checkboxes
- Div `container` is hidden by default, on checkbox click display ( if array is not null) when all checkboxes are unchecked hide(remove data append)
- Display in Div`<li>` Value ( Product ID ) of the two selected Items

please any hints is appreciated. 
**HTML**

```
// checkboxes from loop

<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $res['id'];?>" class="bottomRight" id="<?php echo $res['id'];?>" title="Compare" style="float:left;"  />


<div id="container" style="display:none;"> 
<p>You have added :</p>
<ul>
<li>First Checkbox Value</li>
<li>Second Checkbox Value</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Get the checkboxes values based on the class

$(".bottomRight").change(function() {
    getValueUsingClass();
 });  });


function getValueUsingClass(){

// declare Array
var chkArray = [];


// look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' 

$(".bottomRight:checked").each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Limit chckArray to store only 2 values by disabling the remaining not `:checked`:

```
var n = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length >= 2;  
$('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr('disabled',n);
```

If `chkArray` is not null show the `<div>` container, and if empty hide and remove the list:

```
if(chkArray.length !== 0){
    $('#container').show();        
}else{
    $('#container').hide(); 
    $('#container > ul').html('');    
}
```

Display selected checkbox as `<li>`:

```
$.each(chkArray, function(i, val) { 
   $('<li>').text(chkArray[i]).appendTo('#container > ul');               
});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FxLQK/3/)

Comment: Hello Mark, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. thank you for the help!! a quick question, in PHP when passing a array or need to print an array value, it would be as echo $chkArray[0] ; echo $chkArray[1] ( in this example, the 2 first values ) how different is it in Jquery? chkArray.toString(); but how to eacho first and second value? or pass it as Post to PHP. just if you hint me any tutorial uot there.. again, thanks!

Comment: If you want to convert one item of the array `toString()`, just specify the index `chkArray[1].toString();`.  If you want to pass the array to PHP you can use JSON, it's a data-interchange language. You first need to encode the array `JSON.stringify(chkArray)` then decode it on the PHP side `$chkArray=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);`